# Letter & Word replacing in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a txt file and have certain words & letters changed into the letter "X" (as a way of censoring certain words found in the email)
I've tried:

```
email_one = open("email_one.txt", "r").read()

def email1(email):
  for words in email:
    if words == "learning algorithms":
      return words.replace("learning algorithms", "X")
```

This is my code though I cannot get it to work, it's supposed to read the email and turn all instances of "learning algorithms" into the letter "X"

I have also searched in similar questions but none of the answers there have been able to help me solve this simple thing...

Comment: ```
def email1(email):
  for words in email:
    if "learning algorithms" in words:
      replaced = words.replace("X", "")
      return replaced
```

 I have also tried this, still not working

Comment: this will help https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-better-profanity-detection-library-with-scikit-learn-3638b2f2c4c2

Comment: thanks! this looks exactly like what I'm trying to do!!

Comment: This can not work for several reasons. First, `email` is a string and you are iterating characters, so `words` can never be `"learning algorithms"`. Second, you are replacing in `words`, not in `email`. Third, you are returning after the first replacement (and never if there is no match).

Comment: Also you never write your words back in the file.

Comment: Well the good thing (in your case) about [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) is that it replaces **ALL** occurrences of the substring. So no loop is needed, just `return email.replace("learning algorithms", "X")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple, It's not working because "learning algorithms" is two words, but you are using a `for` loop which is breaking the string down to the letter.

```
email_one = open("email_one.txt", "r").read()
print(email_one)

def email1(email):
  return email.replace("learning algorithms", "X")

print(email1(email_one))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code:

- `email` is a string and you are iterating characters, so `words` can never be `"learning algorithms"`
- you are replacing in `words`, not in `email`
- you are returning after the first replacement (and not at all if there is no match)

Instead, I suggest using a regular expression and `re.sub` to replace all the bad words:

```
import re

email = """I'm trying to read a txt file and have certain words & letters
changed into the letter "X" (as a way of censoring certain words found in
the email) I've tried:"""
bad_words = ["certain words", "letter"]
pattern = r"\b(" + "|".join(bad_words) + r")\b"
censored = re.sub(pattern, lambda m: "X" * len(m.group()), email)
print(censored)
```

Here, the second parameter to `re.sub` is a callback, replacing the bad word with a number of `X` matching the length of the word. If you want a single `X`, just replace the `lambda` function with `"X"`. Also, the `\b` is a word-boundary, which means that the bad word can not be a part of another word (thus `letter` is replaced, but `letters` is not). Output:

```
I'm trying to read a txt file and have XXXXXXXXXXXXX & letters
changed into the XXXXXX "X" (as a way of censoring XXXXXXXXXXXXX found in
the email) I've tried:
```